# Eliminar parte de un string de manera condicional (Regex)

Tags: php, wordpress, regex

Tengo que hacer un rearch & replace en Wordpress para sustituir todos los enlaces que aparecen siguiendo este formato:

```
https://theamaranta.com/.image/c_fit,h_600,w_600/MTQ0NzQzOTE3MzMyNDczMDAw/nostalgia_fotos_antiguas_de_fiestas_en_studio_54_43567410_1200x.jpg
https://theamaranta.com/.image/c_fit,h_600,w_600/MTQ0NzQzOTE4NDA2MjE0NzAy/20_5794a9dc-cca9-46e6-a6a5-bf2c7b04ff02.jpg
```

Por un formato como este:

```
https://theamaranta.com/nostalgia_fotos_antiguas_de_fiestas_en_studio_54_43567410_1200x 
https://theamaranta.com/20_5794a9dc-cca9-46e6-a6a5-bf2c7b04ff02
```

Nótese que se elimina también el ".jpg" al final.

Bien, con la expresión regular `\/.image\/c_fit,h_600,w_600\/.{24}/g` soy capaz de seleccionar la parte "central" del string para sustituirlo por `""`. Ahora bien, para borrar el ".jpg" no puedo buscar únicamente por ".jpg", ya que eliminaría otros enlaces que no me intetesa eliminar. Debería seleccionar únicamente los que NO tienen el string "wp-content/uploads" por delante. De manera que los enlaces tipo

```
http://theamaranta.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/shrek.jpg
```

no se vean afectados.

¿Alguien sabe cómo se puede hacer esto únicamente usando expresiones regulares por favor?

Gracias

Comment: Para que te podamos ayudar mejor: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: No se mucho de wordpress y no se si lo que estás intentando hacer está embebido como funcionalidad de wordpress o lo haces en algun lenguaje o por consola, pero yo usaria `sed` para buscar los 2 patrones y reemplazarlos (eliminarlos), es una opción usar `sed`?

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que al importar unos posts a Wordpress desde otra plataforma se han quedado los enlaces de las imágenes de los posts como estaban antiguamente, y necesito que ahora sigan el patrón de wordpress. Para ello se me había ocurrido usar el típico plugin "Regex search and replace".

Comment: "sed" podría usarlo sí, pero no tengo ni idea de cómo sería el patrón que habría que pasarle :/

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
(:\/\/[^\/]+\/)(?!wp-content\/uploads\/).*?([\w-]+)[.]jpg
```

Remplazar por:

```
\1\2
```

**Explicado**:

```
(:\/\/[^\/]+\/)                 # Grupo de captura 1: :// + cualquier caracter
                                # excepto / una o más veces y luego /
(?!wp-content\/uploads\/).*?    # Cualquier caracter 0 o más veces. No debe 
                                # empezar por wp-content/uploads/
([\w-]+)                        # Grupo de captura 2: Caracter que puedes ser
                                # letras, números, underscores o guión 1 o más veces
[.]jpg                          # .jpg literal
```

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/WbDqln/2/).

Answer (score 0):

**Usando perl por consola (sed no soporta expresiones tipo `?...`):**

Asumiendo que tienes tus direcciones en un archivo `test.txt`, así:

```
https://theamaranta.com/.image/c_fit,h_600,w_600/MTQ0NzQzOTE3MzMyNDczMDAw/nostalgia_fotos_antiguas_de_fiestas_en_studio_54_43567410_1200x.jpg
https://theamaranta.com/.image/c_fit,h_600,w_600/MTQ0NzQzOTE4NDA2MjE0NzAy/20_5794a9dc-cca9-46e6-a6a5-bf2c7b04ff02.jpg
https://theamaranta.com/20_5794a9dc-cca9-46e6-a6a5-bf2c7b04ff02.jpg
http://theamaranta.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/shrek.jpg
```

Puede usar este comando:

```
$ cat test.txt | perl -ne 's/^(http.*com)(\/.image\/c_fit,h_600,w_600\/.{24}|(?!\/wp-content))(.*)(.jpg)$/\1\3/g; print;'

https://theamaranta.com/nostalgia_fotos_antiguas_de_fiestas_en_studio_54_43567410_1200x
https://theamaranta.com/20_5794a9dc-cca9-46e6-a6a5-bf2c7b04ff02
https://theamaranta.com/20_5794a9dc-cca9-46e6-a6a5-bf2c7b04ff02
http://theamaranta.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/shrek.jpg
```

---

**Explicación:**

Si revisas este [enlace](https://regex101.com/r/Gxsz3x/4/), puedes ver un expresion regular que te puede servir.

```
^(.*)(\/.image\/c_fit,h_600,w_600\/.{24})(.*)(.jpg)$
```

Lo que hace es reconocer 4 grupos:

- `^`: Inicio
- `(.*)`: Grupo 1
- `(\/.image\/c_fit,h_600,w_600\/.{24})`: Grupo 2
- `(.*)`: Grupo 3
- `(.jpg)`: Grupo 4
- `$`: fin

Y luego en la parte de sustitución, solo se usan los grupos 1 y 3, que es lo que necesitas.

Por ejemplo:

```
https://theamaranta.com
/.image/c_fit,h_600,w_600/MTQ0NzQzOTE4NDA2MjE0NzAy
/20_5794a9dc-cca9-46e6-a6a5-bf2c7b04ff02
.jpg
```

`\1\3` = `https://theamaranta.com/20_5794a9dc-cca9-46e6-a6a5-bf2c7b04ff02`

---

**Si ya has eliminado la parte central y ahora tienes solo que eliminar el `.jpg`**:

Prueba esta expresión:

`^(http.*com)(\/.image\/c_fit,h_600,w_600\/.{24}|(?!\/wp-content))(.*)(.jpg)$`

Funciona de la misma forma, solo que valida que no contenga `wp-content` en el segundo grupo

---